# Reading height values from texture in vertex shader

Tags: opengl, texture2d

I have a geotiff from SRTM. I send it on GPU, in a vertex shader as a sampler2D.
Thus i have it as a sampler2D uniform. All that i want is to read height data from
that sampler2D (in vertex shader). I dont want use gl_Vertex.

Comment: pass height as a uniform. Because height of a texture remains the same throughout its lifetime, it's highly unlikely it would be manipulated at run-time (if so, it would be expensive and inefficient).

Comment: the technic is called 'vertex displacement', seek for it...

Comment: @Poriferous: The texture's data *is the height*. The whole point of what he's asking about is the ability for the height to be defined by locations stored in a texture. It is not a "uniform" value because it changes from vertex to vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called Vertex Texture Fetch.

There's an older [article on the OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Texture_Fetch) about it, but essentially you bind the texture to a texture unit, make sure the uniform sampler2D is set to the same texture unit, then call `texture2D(myTex, coords)` in your shader.

Your coordinates can be set up in a number of ways, but the goal is to make it simple to turn a vertex coordinate to a texture coordinate in the [0, 1] range.